# Finding the general formula of a sequence alternating between even and odd

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

So I know how to find the general formula of a simple sequence and sequences involving alternating signs but how would you devise a general formula for sequqences alternating between even and odd numbers with different operations occuring to even and odd numbers For example we have the sequence

```
                    13, 17, 23, 27, 33, 37...
```

The sequence starts at 13 and as you can see if the number of the term is odd then we add 4 and if it's even we add 6. I have also devised two separate formula for even and odd numbers. For example if we have to find the 2oth term we use the formula (10n + 7) as 20 is even. If we have to find 21st term we plug it into (10n + 3) as its odd. What I want is a way to devise one general formula for the whole sequence. Is there even a way to do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How about $a_n=10\lceil{n/2}\rceil+7-4(n\bmod2)$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an answer using simple arithmetics:
$$5\Big(n+\frac{3-(-1)^n}2\Big)+2\cdot(-1)^n$$

Comment: could you explain how this works

Comment: Yes you are right but could you please explain it a bit

Comment: @abdullahaquarius Do you know the exponentiation? $a^n = \underbrace{a\cdot a\cdot\ldots\cdot a}_{n\text{ times}}$. In this case, $(-1)(-1)\ldots(-1)$ is either $1$ or $-1$ depending on $n$.

Comment: Okay I got it. thanks a lot. I had gotten to the part of 5(n+1+(-1)^n)+2 * (-1)^n

Comment: But that didn't work with one, but yours does so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Apart the possibilities already suggested (use of $mod$ and use of $(-1)^n$, you can also use the floor function
$$
f(n) = 6n+7-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor
$$

Comment: could you explain how this works

Comment: @abdullahaquarius  I assume you know the floor function. $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ is equal to $n/2$ if $n$ is even and is equal to $(n-1)/2$ if $n$ is odd. Hence, twice that it is equal to $n$ if $n$ is even and $n-1$ if $n$ is odd. So in practice the formula is $6n+7-n=5n+7$ when $n$ is even, giving the terms $\cdot,17,\cdot,27,\cdots$ and it is equal to $6n+7-(n-1)=5n+6$ when $n$ is odd, giving the terms $13,\cdot,23,\cdot,33,\cdots$.